# delete all html tag and limit letters php

Tags: php

i have made this php script:

```
//save the data into a variable
$testo = $news['testo'];

//delete all tag html
$testo = strip_tags($testo);

?>
<?php print "<p>".substr($testo,0,400)."...</p>"; ?>
```

First i take the variable and after i delete all tag and limit the letters to 400.

But there is a problem, the letters are different from article and article. Like: 393 letter, 378 letter, ecc.

how can I fix it ? I want the same number of letter for every article.

Comment: You could get the minimum string length and use it as the delimiter.

Comment: how? can you post an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-line solution with `mb_substr`(if `$news['testo']` has at least 400 characters):

```
<?php

$testo = (isset($news['testo']))? mb_substr(trim(strip_tags($news['testo'])), 0, 400) : "";

print "<p>". $testo ."...</p>"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$length = strlen($testo);

//Cut text longer than 400 so it ends with ...
if ($length > 400)
   $testo = substr($testo, 0, 397).'...';

//Fill text shorter than 400 with * characters
if ($length < 400)
   $testo = str_pad($testo, 400, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

**UPDATE**: you might also have an issue with UTF-8 characters, in that case you should use:

`mb_strlen` and `mb_substr` which will be able handle UTF-8